# ¿Como resetear o indeterminar un bootstrapswitch?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, bootstrap-3, bootstrap-switch

Tengo un checkbox con estilo [bootstrap-switch](http://bootstrapswitch.com/documentation-2.html), cuando ejecuto la vista lo crea con el valor "indeterminado", si ejecuto `state` puedo cambiarle el valor a `true` o `false`, pero no logro colocarlo en "indeterminado" como al principio. En los [ejemplos](http://bootstrapswitch.com/examples.html) hay uno que hace lo que yo quiero (Indeterminate) que es volverlo a "indeterminate" con un botón.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.fn.bootstrapSwitch.defaults.onText = 'Si';
  $.fn.bootstrapSwitch.defaults.offText = 'No';
  $.fn.bootstrapSwitch.defaults.indeterminate = true;
  $.fn.bootstrapSwitch.defaults.animate = false;

  $('.checkbox_switch').bootstrapSwitch();
});

$(document).on('click', '#si', function() {
  $('#crear_neumat').bootstrapSwitch('state' , true);
});

$(document).on('click', '#indeter', function() {
  $('#crear_neumat').bootstrapSwitch('state' , null);
});

$(document).on('click', '#no', function() {
  $('#crear_neumat').bootstrapSwitch('state' , false);
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-switch/3.3.4/css/bootstrap3/bootstrap-switch.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-switch/3.3.4/js/bootstrap-switch.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox_switch" name="crear_neumat" id="crear_neumat">

<button type="button" id="si" class="btn btn-primary">Si</button>
<button type="button" id="indeter" class="btn btn-primary">Indeterminado</button>
<button type="button" id="no" class="btn btn-primary">No</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En la [documentación de Bootstrap Switch](http://bootstrapswitch.com/methods.html) puedes ver que hay varios métodos disponibles. Uno de ellos es `toggleIndeterminate` que cambiará el estado a indeterminado.

Entonces sólo tendrías que usar ese método de la siguiente manera:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.fn.bootstrapSwitch.defaults.onText = 'Si';
  $.fn.bootstrapSwitch.defaults.offText = 'No';
  $.fn.bootstrapSwitch.defaults.indeterminate = true;
  $.fn.bootstrapSwitch.defaults.animate = false;

  $('.checkbox_switch').bootstrapSwitch();
});

$(document).on('click', '#si', function() {
  $('#crear_neumat').bootstrapSwitch('state' , true);
});

$(document).on('click', '#indeter', function() {
  $('#crear_neumat').bootstrapSwitch('toggleIndeterminate');
});

$(document).on('click', '#no', function() {
  $('#crear_neumat').bootstrapSwitch('state' , false);
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-switch/3.3.4/css/bootstrap3/bootstrap-switch.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-switch/3.3.4/js/bootstrap-switch.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox_switch" name="crear_neumat" id="crear_neumat">

<button type="button" id="si" class="btn btn-primary">Si</button>
<button type="button" id="indeter" class="btn btn-primary">Indeterminado</button>
<button type="button" id="no" class="btn btn-primary">No</button>
```

Comment: Genial, no me percate de esa opción, gracias.